# Usage of "ain't" in formal conversation

Tags: word-usage, formality, contractions, speech

Is it okay to use *ain't* in formal conversation?

I know *ain't* can be used for *am not, is not, are not, have not, has not.* So if I can use it in day-to-day life, it will be easier for me I guess.

Comment: Like all other aspects of language, it depends on who you're talking to and why you're talking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not the ideal phrase for a formal conversation. Maybe in commercials, music etc. but not in formal usage between someone you don't know. I mean if you use it in a supermarket it is OK, but kind of weird during a job interview or when talking with a doctor or somebody who you want to show some respect. But I will use it in marketing, commercials, music and stuff of that sort.